# Getting "java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter" for a @GeneratedValue field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.0 with Mysql 5.5.15. I have an entity with a @GeneratedValue ID field. When I try to persist the entity it throws exception: No value specified for parameter 5. The fifth parameter is the ID field. How can I fix this problem?

The entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DEVICE_HISTORY")
public class DeviceHistory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "DEVICE_ID")
    private String deviceId;


    @Column(name = "GUID", length = 36)
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date updated;

    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DeviceStatus status;

    // getters,setters ...

    @PrePersist
    public void setInitialState() {
        setUpdated(new Date());
    }

}
```

The code persisting the entity:

```
DeviceHistory deviceHistory = new DeviceHistory();
deviceHistory.setGuid(guid);
deviceHistory.setDeviceId(deviceId);
deviceHistory.setStatus(DeviceStatus.INACTIVE);
entityManager.persist(deviceHistory);
```

The stack trace:

```
06:12:58,123 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No value specified for parameter 5
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceHistory]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:219)
    at com.evolok.idm.core.domain.RestrictedUnregisterPerDurationDeviceManagementPolicyDelegate.unregisterDevice(RestrictedUnregisterPerDurationDeviceManagementPolicyDelegate.java:78)
    at com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceManagementPolicyEntity.unregisterDevice(DeviceManagementPolicyEntity.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:157)
    at com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceManagementPolicyEntity$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2ff84b00.unregisterDevice(<generated>)
    at com.evolok.idm.services.core.UserProfileComponent.unregisterDevice(UserProfileComponent.java:479)
    at com.evolok.idm.notification.proxies.UserProfileServiceNotificationProxy.unregisterDevice(UserProfileServiceNotificationProxy.java:186)
    at com.evolok.idm.services.web.endpoints.rest.UserProfileResource.unregisterDevice(UserProfileResource.java:567)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sca4j.pojo.component.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.sca4j.pojo.component.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:165)
    at org.sca4j.fabric.component.scope.RequestScopeInterceptor.invoke(RequestScopeInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.sca4j.rs.runtime.RsSourceWireAttacher$RsMethodInterceptor.intercept(RsSourceWireAttacher.java:163)
    at com.evolok.idm.services.web.endpoints.rest.UserProfileResource$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$99ca8d93.unregisterDevice(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:156)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
    at org.sca4j.rs.runtime.rs.RsWebApplication.service(RsWebApplication.java:148)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.sca4j.runtime.webapp.ServletHostImpl.service(ServletHostImpl.java:138)
    at org.sca4j.runtime.webapp.SCA4JServlet.service(SCA4JServlet.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1351)
    at com.evolok.idm.web.TransactionFilter.doFilter(TransactionFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceHistory]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:213)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1993)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 83 more
```

The generated statement:

```
insert into T_DEVICE_HISTORY (DEVICE_ID, GUID, STATUS, UPDATE_DATE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

EDIT: Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `T_DEVICE_HISTORY` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DEVICE_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UPDATE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Edit 2 - persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="evolok-idm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceHistory</class>
        <!--  other classes... -->

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evolok-idm-web"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="4"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: do you have auto-increment in your id field?

Comment: Yes, when I check the table structure the field is: `ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that the updateDate is missing... is tat nullable field ?

AUTO is default strategy so you can remove. and try the following equivalent definition..

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
```

Comment: Updated the post with table structure.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove @Id and @Column and leave just @GeneratedValue ? That gives exception at startup:  `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.evolok.idm.core.domain.DeviceHistory`

Comment: I did not mean that. It s my typo.. I updated the post.. Obviously we will get No identifier specified for entity error when the entity has no id..

Comment: You can also look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788483/hibernate-rundown-on-how-generatedvalue-works)

Comment: Removing strategy didn't help, still getting the same exception. Sorry somehow missed your comment re updateDate, that's being set by @PrePersist method in entity class.

Comment: Thanks. The link helped to understand better what's going on under the hood (or at least what should be). Thought the IDENTITY might be the right choice in my case, but that didn't work either...

Comment: AUTO should work fine with MySQL. Please show your config including where dialect is specified.

Comment: Added the config in the post.

Comment: @AlanHay Could you please check if there is anything missing in my config?

Answer (score 0):

Change your entity as follows, you need to add default constructor.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "T_DEVICE_HISTORY")
    public class DeviceHistory implements java.io.Serializable  {

        public DeviceHistory(){
          super();
          id = null ;
        }


        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
```

Comment: My field is of primitive type, so can't assign null in constructor. Could having a primitive type cause a problem? And also how would adding a default constructor help? If I don't specify any constructor, the default is there anyway doing exactly the same thing, calling super().