# Hibernate 4 and Postgres : How to create a sequence per table?

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I use Hibernate 4 to use mapping to a Postgres database. Before doing mapping i create first java entities. And then, i use a java class to generate sql script from my entities. Here is my entities :

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myusers")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="fistname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;
....
}
```

Project entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
..
}
```

I've noticed that `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` produces the same sequence for table myusers and projects. If i create the first record on myusers table the id will have "1" as value and then when i create the first record in table projects, this record will have id =2. They use both the same sequence. 
I want to know how i cannot modify my entities to specify to Hibernate to create a sequence for each table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: rundown on how @GeneratedValue works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788483/hibernate-rundown-on-how-generatedvalue-works)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on a recent Hibernate, try:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

If it still uses a sequence per table use:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="mytable_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="mytable_id_seq", sequenceName="mytable_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

See [hibernate could not get next sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10628099/398670)