# How to handle gapless sequence with JPA and Postgres?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm developing a REST API with Spring, Spring JPA, Hibernate and Postgresql.
I have a requirement in which I need to have a sequence of codes in an entity.

Consider the following entity:

```
public class Document{
    private Long id;
    private String code;

    //getters and setters
}
```

In my spring method I'm doing something like this to save a new `entity`:

```
    String prefix = "D";

    //get records
    List<Document> documents = this.documentRepository.findAll();

    //find max value of code
    int max = 0;
    for(Document d:documents){
        String code = d.getCode();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(prefix.length()));
        if(number>max) max = number;
    }

    //increment
    long currentNumber = max+1;

    entity.setCode(prefix+currentNumber);

    this.documentRepository.save(entity);
```

This led me to a situation where if I try to call this method twice, I get two documents with the same `code`.

To solve this I tried adding `@Transactional` and `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` annotation to my method. The transaction is being created correctly, but then one of the api invocations fails with

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
```

From what I read about isolation levels, `SERIALIZABLE` is what I need. Also, it looks like Postgres takes a "positive" approach to this isolation level, expecting that both transactions commit successfully. However, that may not always be the case, and the client application is expected to retry the failing transaction.

Observations:

- if an existing document `D4` is **deleted**, it is accepted that the next created document becomes `D5`. So, this isn't so "gapless" as the name itself states.
- my real use case is a bit more complex. I'm not just doing a `findAll`, I just simplified for the sake of this question. In my case imagine that `Document`s are contained in a `Folder`. The gapless sequence is just **among** that folder and not globally. Each `Folder` has many `Documents`. So, for each folder we have `D1`,`D2`,`D3`,...

Acceptable solutions:

- make spring retry the transaction if it fails
- alternative approach to this gapless sequence problem
- would table locking work?

Comment: Why not just use JPA's `@GeneratedValue`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788483/hibernate-rundown-on-how-generatedvalue-works (*So, this isn't so "gapless" as the name itself states.* -- this is what a sequence does anyway)

Comment: Why does it need to be *gapless*?  To truly ensure that in a concurrent or distributed system would be quite a challenge.  Typically sequentially increasing with gaps is sufficient, as you still maintain order (but, again, in a concurrent system that order is up for debate as well)

Comment: @pozs, does that approach assures transactional isolation? I don't think that approach would work because that enforces a "global" sequence? I'm looking for multiple sequences among `Document`. Each `Folder` has many `Documents`. So, for each folder we have `D1`,`D2`,`D3`,...

Comment: @Alex It needs to be gapless because it is simply a requirement of the system. The only situation where we can relax that requirement is on deleted entities. If we delete an entity in the "middle", we can live with that gap.

Comment: @miguelcobain, then from a design point of view, it's not a gapless system...  hopefully your team has a realization of how difficult what you're proposing would be to have work 100%.  That sounds like a arbitrarily chosen design decision (not a technical limitation) that will haunt you for a long time to come

Comment: @Alex, you're right. it's not "strictly" gapless. I couldn't find a better name. It's a regular sequence, but *scoped* to the `Document`s of a parent entity `Folder`. I could save the most recent sequence number in the parent entity, now that I think of it...

Answer (score 0):

> From what I read about isolation levels, SERIALIZABLE is what I need

You'll get a very high rollback rate if there are many conflicts this way.

I suggest a locking approach instead.

Have a sequence generator table. In this table, acquire a new value with a native query:

```
UPDATE mysequencetable SET nextvalue = nextvalue + 1 RETURNING nextvalue
```

You'll still have to deal with retries, though, because if you have multiple such tables your transactions can acquire rows in a different order and then deadlock.

So your application *must* be able to retry transactions. A well written application must do this anyway, otherwise it will not behave properly if the database is restarted, temporarily becomes inaccessible, etc.

Now, if you have to renumber on `DELETE`s as well that's a different problem, you'll need a trigger for that.