# Hibernate programmatically get incremented ID

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Table Generator to generate primary keys for all the tables. Recently I received a requirement which I need to get the incremented id programmatically without persisting the entity into the database.
I believe it can be achieved by calling hibernate internal API.
Anyway knows how to get the incremented id programmatically with hibernate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788483/hibernate-rundown-on-how-generatedvalue-works

Comment: But it never explained on how to get the id programatically.

Comment: You just need to add `@GeneratedValue` annotation over your ID field and hibernate will automatically choose the most appropriate way to generate IDs.

Comment: May be my question is not clear enough. I have edited my question. Kindly refers to the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into NHibernat code (most certainly it works for Hibernate the same). You can call the id generator, but this won't help much, because the generated ID won't be used when storing an object.

This is something which does conceptually not work. You cannot have a system generate IDs automatically and have it generated outside of the storing procedure at the same time.

These are the options that come to my mind:

- Use ID generator "assigned" and generate the ids yourself. This is the only way how you can assign an ID which had been defined before storing. (Note that it is not trivial to generate unique numbers in a system of concurrent transactions.) It's not very comfortable for your code as you will see.
- Question the requirement. As soon as an object is identified to the user, shouldn't it be persistent?
- Consider separating the visible ID from the primary key. It might be an overkill to have to IDs in the system just to have on defined before the other, but otherwise it decouples your primary keys from user data. You could switch to other ID generators due to technical reasons without conflicting with requirements. (Similar to the first item, but not messing with primary keys anymore.)

Comment: I need to implement this because i need a running number to construct the code that will persist into database later. eg. US-ABC-1000001 and I don't want to create a sequence number for this.

Comment: If you want to have it as described, you need to either have an assignable primary key or separate the "US-ABC-1000001" part from the primary key. In both cases you need to manage the sequence number yourself. You probably can (mis)use Hibernate ID generators for this. ID generators usually do not have much code and you could also just implement it yourself.