# Duplicate id with mysql in hibernate on google app engine

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine

My setup is Appengine + hibernate + mysql

Sometimes app is throwing exception:

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions: Duplicate entry '466' for key 'PRIMARY'

unfortunately it happens not often and can not be easy reproduced.

My entities are constructed like this:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Game")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long srvId;
    ...
```

I know Google App Engine does not support Identity as generator strategy. Thing I have noticed is that after redeploying app problem disappears. Then it can occur again after some time. Weird thing is that in logs of GAE I can see that during exception there is no other request proceed, and even when request is retried, exception is thrown again after 15 sec. (15 sec is time between requests) After 1 minute problem disappears.

Is it related to cache ? (I do not have configured any) or multiple sql instances on app engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already thought of this, and this answer may be too basic, but does your method use the auto increment function in mysql?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788483/hibernate-rundown-on-how-generatedvalue-works) gives a breakdown on the @GeneratedValue annotation. Also, I did not see the `strategy=` attribute in your code, and I have seen it in most other examples.

Comment: after investigation I have noticed that now autoincrement was added to SQL schema. Before there was no AUTOINCREMENT next to the key. Thanks!